# Error trying to integrate simple form with google sheets with vercel

Tags: javascript, google-sheets-api, vercel, server-side

I am trying to connect a simple HTML form I made with google sheets to collect form responses using Vercel for deployment. I am very novice with anything server-side.

I get this error in the console every time I try to submit to the form:

"Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'A', "A server e"... is not valid JSON"
and this in Vercel dashboard

```
"Unhandled Promise Rejection    {"errorType":"Runtime.UnhandledPromiseRejection","errorMessage":"TypeError: doc.useServiceAccountAuth is not a function","reason":{"errorType":"TypeError","errorMessage":"doc.useServiceAccountAuth is not a function","stack":["TypeError: doc.useServiceAccountAuth is not a function","    at module.exports (/var/task/api/submit.js:6:19)",""
```

This is my submit.js

```
const { GoogleSpreadsheet } = require('google-spreadsheet');

module.exports = async (req, res) => {
    if (req.method === 'POST') {
        const doc = new GoogleSpreadsheet('sheet-id');
        await doc.useServiceAccountAuth(require('../sheets/service-account.json'));
        await doc.loadInfo();

        const sheet = doc.sheetsByIndex[0]; 
        const result = await sheet.addRow({ Suggestion: req.body.suggestion, Timestamp: new Date().toLocaleString() });

        res.status(200).json({ message: 'Suggestion added to Google Sheet' });
    } else {
        res.status(405).json({ error: 'Method not allowed' });
    }
};
```

I've tried changing up my Submit.js code but got the same exact error. I also tried reinstalling google-spreadsheet through npm but the problem isn't there it's definitely in the package list.

Thanks for any help with this!